# Google Cloud Platform send weird classes

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using `CloudPubSubSourceConnector` to Subscribe to GCP and once I get an event I publish in the Kafka Topic

Here my GCPKafkaConnect

```
{
    "connector.class": "com.google.pubsub.kafka.source.CloudPubSubSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "kafka.topic": "My-Updates",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"Updates-Failed",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": true,
    "errors.log.enable": true,
    "errors.log.include.messages": true,
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": 60000,
    "errors.retry.timeout": 300000,
    "cps.subscription":"hk_subscription",
    "cps.project":"hub-dev",
    "gcp.credentials.file.path":"/tmp/gcp/gcp.json",
    "gcp.credentials.json":"gcp.json",
    "kafka.partition.count": 3
  }
```

All the info that I send with `gcloud` command is encode

```
 gcloud pubsub topics publish hk_subscription_pubsub_topic --message="aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
```

Then when I subscribe to the Topic, I dont know why sometimes I receive the encoded text

```
Json encoded string aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=
```

And the half of the time,  like a class that cannot be decoded

```
Json encoded string [B@66976faa
```

Any idea about this issue?

Regards.

Comment: The first looks like base64 data. The other is just a byte array... Have you tried using ByteArrayConverter instead of StringConverter? What about JSONConverter since that's the only converter with the schema enable property you've added? (strings don't have schemas)

Comment: I try with all converters(byte,string,Json) and with all of them I still receiving half of the time the proper byte array encoded, and the other time that class name, that I cannot deserialize. Don’t understand why, since I’m sending the same message all the time

Comment: The json converter should at least return data adhering to the schema mentioned here https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-gcp-pubsub/current/overview.html#record-schema

Comment: Also, what exactly are you using to consume?

Comment: Apache Kafka consumer with JsonConverter and also I tried with ByteArrayDeserializer

Comment: JSONConverter can't be used in consumers. ByteArrayDeserializer will definitely always show something like `[B@66976faa`. You should use StringDeserializer, at least, if you're using StringConverter or JSONConverter in Connect

Comment: Thanks I will try both in Consumer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by OneCricketeer :

> [JSONConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) can't be used in consumers.
> [ByteArrayDeserializer](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer.html) will definitely always show something like
> `[B@66976faa`. You should use StringDeserializer, at least, if you're
> using StringConverter or JSONConverter in Connect.

For more details on StringDeserializer, you can refer to this [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer.html).

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem that was asked, though, which seems to be decoding base64 data.